# Comparing string against arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList which I need to compare against String.

What I have done:

```
ArrayList<String> val = new ArrayList<String>();
val= getValues();
```

If I print val , it gives me expected values.But

```
if(val.contains("abcd"))
```

It is returning false although at time of printing values of val it consists of abcd.

What can possibly be wrong?

Edited:
How my arraylist is getting values:

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream , write)
str = write.toString()

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(str));
return list;
```

Comment: you need to deep compare it

Comment: does your `getValues()` method return a String?

Comment: No, it is returning arrayList

Comment: May be you need to trim and compare

Comment: @user3505394 what is` getValues()` method i printed `if(val.contains("abcd"))` and it is returning true.Could you plz upload the whole program.

Comment: @user3505394 focus on trim and case sensitive of the value

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_contains.htm use this sample

Comment: no if you have added the abcd as a single element ..it should print true when you call for contains method.

Comment: I guess m facing this issue bcz of spaces. Actually I have converted inputStream to string(str) using IOUtils then copied to ArrayList list.addAll(str). Is this issue bcz of this?

Comment: @user3505394 If you won't paste your code here how would we help you?

Comment: I have edited it, I guess that mayb sufficient.

Comment: @user3505394 plz provide the whole program.

Comment: Finally solved my problem! The issue was with spaces only, I have changed data in my file to comma separated.Earlier it was in line separated. Sorry I cannot provide whole program!

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure that `val` contains `string` exactly as `abcd`(no space, no uppercase). But if it is not case-sensitive and you allow space, then you may check it like this:

```
boolean isExist = false;
for(int i=0;i<val.size();i++){
    if(val.get(i).trim().toLowerCase().equals("abcd")){
        isExist=true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `getValues()` returns an arraylist of strings, you need to ensure that the string "abcd" is exactly as given in parameter. Also since according to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), the contains method implements the `equals` method for comparison, you should make sure that the string has the right case as equals is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

contain() method works by comparing elements of Arraylist on equals() method. If your arraylist has "abcd", it should return 'true'. Try checking if your getValues() method returns some hidden character/space along with "abcd".

Answer (score -1):

do something like below.

```
for(int i=0;i<val.size();i++){
    if(val.get(i).contains("abcd") || val.get(i).contains("ABCD")){
      // do some thing here
    }
}
```

Comment: may i know the reason of down-vote of my ans and up-vote for aprox same ans